# Bulk update with TypeORM query builder doesn't work

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am developing an NodeJS(NestJS) project with TypeORM and using Postgresql database.

My table schema:

```
                                          Table "public.users"
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |              Default
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id             | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at     | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 invalidated_at | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 group          | uuid                        |           |          |

Indexes:
    "PK_3001e89ada36263dabf1fb6210a" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "user_group_idx" btree (group)
```

The associated entity:

```
@Entity('users')
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'bigint' })
  id: string | undefined;


  @Column({ type: 'timestamp' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ type: 'uuid', nullable: true })
  @Generated('uuid')
  group: string | null;

}
```

I try to do bulk update to update the `group` value by:

```
const ids = [34, 36, 38];
// also tried : const ids = ['34', '36', '38'];
const result = await conn
        .createQueryBuilder(UserEntity, 'users')
        .update(UserEntity)
        .set({ group: 'new group' })
        .where({ id: In(ids) })
        .execute();

console.log(`result : ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
```

But the console log shows me 0 affected rows:  `result : {"generatedMaps":[],"raw":[],"affected":0}`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: you could [enable typeorm logs](https://typeorm.io/#/logging) and monitor the querys it's running